# Reshaping data in Python (List/array)

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, numpy, reshape

I have the following Numpy array.
[image]

I want to reshape it to be (3,5,3)

So i must be like:

```
[
[
[1,6,11],
[2,7,12],
[3,8,13],
[4,9,14],
[5,10,15]
],.......
]
```

I tried reshape(3,5,3) but it doesn't give the wanted result?

Comment: "doesn't give the wanted result" is not specific enough. What result did you expect, and which one did you actually get? What code gave you this result?

Comment: `aaa.transpose(0,2,1)`?

Comment: I guess you're using numpy. so you should give the new shape as a tuple `myarray.reshape((3,5,3))` (double brackets)

Comment: Thank you @Divakar

Answer (score 1):

Your input array is of shape `(3, 3, 5)` and you want it to be reshaped it to `(3, 5, 3)`. There are many ways of doing this. Below are some, as also mentioned in the comments:

First would be to use [**`numpy.reshape()`**](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html) which accepts `newshape` as a parameter:

```
In [77]: arr = np.arange(3*3*5).reshape(3, 3, 5)

# reshape to desired shape
In [78]: arr = arr.reshape((3, 5, 3))

In [79]: arr.shape
Out[79]: (3, 5, 3)
```

Or you can use [**`numpy.transpose()`**](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.transpose.html) as in:

```
In [80]: arr = np.arange(3*3*5).reshape(3, 3, 5)

In [81]: arr.shape
Out[81]: (3, 3, 5)

# now, we want to move the last axis which is 2 to second position
# thus our new shape would be `(3, 5, 3)`
In [82]: arr = np.transpose(arr, (0, 2, 1))

In [83]: arr.shape
Out[83]: (3, 5, 3)
```

Another way would be to use [**`numpy.moveaxis()`**](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.moveaxis.html) :

```
In [87]: arr = np.arange(3*3*5).reshape(3, 3, 5)

# move the last axis (-1) to 2nd position (1)
In [88]: arr = np.moveaxis(arr, -1, 1)

In [89]: arr.shape
Out[89]: (3, 5, 3)
```

Yet another way would be to just swap the axes using [**`numpy.swapaxes()`**](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.swapaxes.html) :

```
In [90]: arr = np.arange(3*3*5).reshape(3, 3, 5)

In [91]: arr.shape
Out[91]: (3, 3, 5)

# swap the position of ultimate and penultimate axes
In [92]: arr = np.swapaxes(arr, -1, 1)

In [93]: arr.shape
Out[93]: (3, 5, 3)
```

Choose whichever is more intuitive to you since all approaches return a new *view* of the desired shape.

---

Although all of the above return a view, there are some timing differences. So, the preferred way of doing this (for efficiency) would be:

```
In [124]: arr = np.arange(3*3*5).reshape(3, 3, 5)

In [125]: %timeit np.swapaxes(arr, -1, 1)
456 ns ± 6.79 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)

In [126]: %timeit np.transpose(arr, (0, 2, 1))
458 ns ± 6.93 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)

In [127]: %timeit np.reshape(arr, (3, 5, 3))
635 ns ± 9.06 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)

In [128]: %timeit np.moveaxis(arr, -1, 1)
3.42 µs ± 79.6 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

`numpy.swapaxes()` and `numpy.transpose()` takes almost the same time, with `numpy.reshape()` being a bit slower, while `numpy.moveaxis` being the slowest among all. So, it'd be wise to use either `swapaxes` or `transpose` ufunc.

Comment: Which of these would be the most efficient to work with?

Comment: @KartikeySingh Added an explanation for this. HTH :)

Comment: It depends on data case as here it is better to use `transpose` but most of the time we need `reshape` and `transpose` cannot be used there. Thank you for the explanation :)

Answer (score 0):

I found a way of doing it using `List comprehension` and `Numpy transpose`.

Code:

```
import numpy as np
database = [
        [
            [1,2,3,4,5],
            [6,7,8,9,10],
            [11,12,13,14,15]
        ],
        [
            [16,17,18,19,20],
            [21,22,23,24,25],
            [26,27,28,29,30]
        ],
        [
            [31,32,33,34,35],
            [36,37,38,39,40],
            [41,42,43,44,45]
        ]
    ]

ans = [np.transpose(data) for data in database]
print(ans)
```

Output:

```
[array([[ 1,  6, 11],
       [ 2,  7, 12],
       [ 3,  8, 13],
       [ 4,  9, 14],
       [ 5, 10, 15]]), 
 array([[16, 21, 26],
       [17, 22, 27],
       [18, 23, 28],
       [19, 24, 29],
       [20, 25, 30]]), 
 array([[31, 36, 41],
       [32, 37, 42],
       [33, 38, 43],
       [34, 39, 44],
       [35, 40, 45]])]
```